# updating returned json with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am initially showing JSON based on 'item.crime1', but I want to update 'crime1' based on my onChangeCrime function. It's kind of working but it seems to be delayed. I'm new to hooks so I suspect it could be that.

api.js

```
    axios.get(apiCall)
            .then(res => {
                const x = res.data.results;
                setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, totalData: x }))


                x.sort(function (a, b) {
                    return a.year - b.year;
                });
                const data = {
                    labels: x.map(item => item.year),
                    datasets: [{
                        data: x.map(item => item.crime1)
                    }],
                }
                setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, isLoading: false, dataSort: data }));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("error...", error)
            })
```

```
       const onChangeCrime = (e) => {
        let val = e.target.value;
        setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, sortByCrime: val }));

        let x = totalData;
        x.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.year - b.year;
        });
        const data = {
            labels: x.map(item => item.year),
            datasets: [{
                data: x.map(item => item[sortByCrime])
            }],
        }
        setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, isLoading: false, dataSort: data }));
    }
```

render.js

```
<div>
   <select name="sortByCrime" value={sortByCrime} onChange={(e) => onChangeCrime(e)}>
      <option value="crime1">All Crime</option>
      <option value="murder">Murder</option>
   </select>
   <Line data={dataSort} />
</div>
```

Comment: Operations like `filter`, `sort` could be done without setting a new data state. You can derive those data easily. `useMemo` is suitable for those kinds of things. So, you'll have one data in your state. There will be one state piece for the sort criteria. You will change these criteria, then get the derived state and use it.

Comment: fixed it by giving up on hooks and switching back to regular old react. gg

Comment: OK, but again the problem was not hooks here.

Comment: i believe it was something to do with hooks and not using a callback. because switching back to regular state and using a callback fixed the issue. i'm still using sort and two data sets.